# +2.5V giving me 1.45V

Tags: power-supply

Are these readings ok? that +2.5v is the DDR's?

```
+2.5V:   1,45V
Vcore:   1,51V
+3.3V:   3,26V
  +5V:   5,14V
 +12V:   12,11V
```

Comment: FWIW, the voltages reported by most tools (CPU-Z, etc.) on my EVGA motherboard are total rubbish, systematically wrong by a volt or two.  The voltages reported in the BIOS, however, are reasonable looking.  I wouldn't trust anything short of a Fluke to mean much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 2,5V PSU line. Motherboard takes care of voltage conversion for that.

In my opinion, 1.45V is problematic, but it may not be related to PSU. Get some other program which can display more voltages and show us the results. Also take a look [here](http://pinouts.ru/Power/atx_v2_pinout.shtml) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX).

Also, which version of DDR is that? If it's DDR3, than it's good. If it's 2 or 1, it's a big problem.

Comment: It's DDR1, last December 4 RAMs just died, could that be the reason? Other readings show the same 1.43 ~ 1.45. It's the mobo then? Everytime I start the PC i hear some "electric noise" coming from the PSU and when something uses the graphic card (windows 7 loading logo) the PC shuts down. After the BIOS tells me there was a problem it just run smoothly, basically I've to start the PC twice or more times, after that it can be on until I decide to turn it off.

Comment: I think (but I could be wrong!) that you have problems with bad capacitors. The fact that you need to start computer multiple time in order for it to start working correctly makes me think that this is the problem. It could be bad capacitors on motherboard, in power-supply or both. Open the case and take a look at them. If they look like something from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague then that's the problem. Otherwise, try to obtain a known good PSU and start your system with it and check voltages. If they are still bad, then it's motherboard. Otherwise it's PSU.

Answer (score 0):

2.5 volts is made by the on-board (on the mother board) step-down power supply unit.

This kind of supply is controlled by a RAM voltage control unit. So if your RAM needs 2.5 volts it regulates the output voltage on 2.5 volts, if the ram needs 1.5 volts it switched on 1.5 volt and so on. Don't worry, it is normal.

If you still not satisfied, check your RAM model and search the internet for appropriate voltage for your installed RAM. It may answer your question.